# What is a chance move?

Tags: game-theory

I am studying the book *Game Theory* by Guillermo Owen and in the next paragraph I do not understand what means a chance move. Could anyone explain to me, please?

> The elements of a game are seen here: condition $\alpha$ states that there is a starting point; $\beta$ gives a payoff function; $\gamma$ divides the moves into ***chance moves ($S_0$)*** and personal moves which correspond to the $n$ players ($S_1,\dots,S_n$); $\delta$ defines a...

The condition gamma reads:

> By an *n-person game in extensive form* is meant:
>
> ($\gamma$) a partition of the nonterminal vertices of $\Gamma$ into $n+1$ sets $S_0,S_1,\dots,S_n$ called the *player sets*

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like they are moves that happen independent of the players' actions.  Maybe a random number is pulled and the state of the game changes depending on the number.  If there is no randomness associated, the change can be counted as part of the last player move.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to come up with situations in which transitions from
>   state to state depend on other chance factors, such as the weather,
>   earthquakes, or the stock market. These sorts of state transitions are
>   called chance moves. To accommodate this feature, our model is
>   expanded by labelling some of the vertices in the game three $(V, E, x)$
>    as chance moves. The edges emanating from vertices corresponding
>   to chance moves represent the possible outcomes of a lottery, and next
>   to each such edge is listed the probability that the outcome it
>   represents will be the result of the lottery.

Michael Meschler, Eilon Solan, Shmuel Zamir, *GAME THEORY*, Cambridge University Press, 2013, p. 49

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, chance moves are actions made by the **God**. It is not decided by players but by God randomly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).